# Matrix position accessing in c

Tags: c, arrays

I am stuck on how to index a matrix in c (codeblocks) using an array.

I have an array `vet[20]` in which I save one int number in each position, which correspond to a line index and a column index of a matrix, `mat[LINES][COLUMNS]`, and I need to use that position inside the array to directly go to my matrix in the positions saved inside the array.

I have tried the following:

```
mat[vet[a]][vet[a+1]];
```

The code line above has caused my application to crash. Any tips on how to solve this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: probably indexing out of bounds ... use your debugger or add print statments and make sure your indices `a` and `a+1` are on the range 0 to 19 and the indices `vec[a]` and `vect[a+1]` are on the ranges 0 to LINES-1 and 0 to COLUMNS-1 respectively

Comment: Would be necessary to see your code, particularly where things are allocated and declared. You being a self proclaimed rookie automatically casts suspicion on your verbal descriptions.

Comment: In `mat[vet[a]][vet[a+1]];` if `vet` holds row references, then `mat[vet[a]][..]` makes sense (so long as all entries in `vet[a]` are valid row numbers for `mat`)... However, `mat[..][vet[a+1]]` makes little or no sense on the surface. (if it is a square matrix -- possibly). We can't read minds, or see your screen from here, so you need to post [**A Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example (MCVE)**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for further help.

Answer (score -2):

Debug your code and make sure that `0 <= a <= 18`.
Then for each value stored in your `vet` matrix (`vet[0] .. vet[19]`), make sure it's not greater than `LINES` and `COLUMNS`.

Need to see your full code to make sure no other lines of code other than the matrix index issue that causing the crash.

Comment: While good general advice, you have no way of knowing if this is an adequate answer.

Comment: @MadPhysicist which is why i said that need to see the full code to make sure that is the root cause. with the current information where op think that the matrix index causing the crash, this is the potential answer

Comment: @RannLifshitz because the question didn't contain a MCVE, it's a poor question and cannot be answered without a large amount of speculation. Hopefully it is clear why people suggest to not answer the question until the author has modified it to meet the posting guidelines for the site